# Movie referencing the three most powerful people in the world

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for a movie with over 20 years (probably), that I saw as a child. It is english, in color, probably about submarines and nuclear warheads (in the lines of 'The Hunt For Red October', probably). I don't remember anything else about the movie, except the initial premise.

The movie starts with text on the screen, and it reads:

> The 3 most powerful people on the planet are:
>
> - the US President
> - the Queen of England
> - the Captain of a Nuclear Submarine

What movie is this? I remember I had it in VHS, but my VHS collection is long gone.

Comment: I think if it is *Crimson Tide*, the beginning is pretty close to your description. If it is I will add as an answer =)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

By the text on the screen, I think your movie is *[Crimson Tide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimson_Tide_(film))*.

> Crimson Tide is a 1995 American submarine film directed by Tony Scott, and produced by Don Simpson and Jerry Bruckheimer. It takes place during a period of political turmoil in the Russian Federation, in which ultranationalists threaten to launch nuclear missiles at the United States and Japan. It focuses on a clash of wills between the new executive officer (Denzel Washington) of a U.S. nuclear missile submarine and its seasoned commanding officer (Gene Hackman), arising from conflicting interpretations of an order to launch their missiles.

Here's a screenshot of the beginning of the movie showing a text close to what you described:

[image: Screenshot beginning of the movie]

Comment: Hey, nice... the font from 24! :D

Answer (score 15):

The movie in question is [*Crimson Tide* (1995)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112740/).  The full movie is available on youtube, and you can see the opening line you describe (the second line is actually "The President of the Russian Republic") in the first 5 seconds of the video:

Comment: Despite being the first answer, Gustavo posted the answer in the comments even earlier. +1 anyway =)